# Cloudwatch Logs config: timestamp_format match

Tags: logging, amazon-cloudwatch

i am missing the part in the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Details.html#CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Logssection) where it is described how the timestamp_format is evaluated within a given line.

Here i have a sample log line:

```
[4138] 2021/07/19 15:20:57.996872 [INF] Listening for client connections on ...
```

As you can see the datetime info is located in the second column. Does Cloudwatch automagically match the configured timestamp_format pattern within the complete line or does it always assume that the datetime column needs to be in the first column?
How can i tell Cloudwatch Agent to use the second column for `timestamp_format` matching?

Answer (score -1):

From experience, it will find the first timestamp that matches `timestamp_format`. From what I've read [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Details.html) is a little ambiguous. There are two statements in the documentation that seem to validate this claim.

Under the `timestamp_format` bullet there is the statement:

```
If a single log entry contains two time stamps that match the format, the first time stamp is used.
```

That indicates to me it is looking through the entire log entry for a match, not just parsing the first date field.

Under the `multi_line_start_pattern` bullet there is the statement:

```
If you include this field, you can specify {timestamp_format} to use the same regular expression as your timestamp format. Otherwise, you can specify a different regular expression for CloudWatch Logs to use to determine the start lines of multi-line entries.
```

That indicates to me again `timestamp_format` used to do pattern matching across the entire log entry.